# Facebook page app deep link

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed a hybrid mobile app using Ionic and I have a Facebook page for my app. On Facebook page, it has a button called "Call-to-Action Button".

When create "Call-to-Action Button" to "use app", it has a field called "deep link". What & how should I put on that field?

Answer (score 0):

ionic app deep linking simply used in other page in which open your app just like

```
mycoolapp://http://xxxxxx.co/#/guest/aaaa
```

above code used for open your app from facebook or other site where mycoolapp is name of app.

for some example doing in site [open](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme#3-usage) 
thanks and good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Let say, I don't need user to go any specific page. I just want it to open my app when the Facebook call-to-action button is clicked. So, what should I put there? Do I still need to get those plugin into my app?